# Proper escaping of Characters for Shell execution from ASP/VBScript

Tags: shell, vbscript, escape-characters, escaping, asp

I am executing a curl call from ASP with the WScript.Shell Object.

```
Set objCmd = objWShell.Exec("cmd.exe /c echo "&dataString&" | /path/to/curl --cacert '/path/to/cert/cacert.pem' -X POST"&options&" -A """&useragent&""""&referer&" -F "&fileParamName&"=@-;type="&fileMIME&";filename=^"""&filename&"^"" --url """&url&"""")
```

What this command does is, sending a curl request with a file appended. The content of the file comes from the `stdin` (the `echo`) for no need to write an actual file to the hard drive.

My problem is, that it seems like some calls are not working properly, because of characters in the `dataString` that break the command. The `dataString` contains JSON with user input from the database.
The JSON contents get encoded already, so that characters get transformed to `\b`, `\t`, `\n`, `\f`, `\r`, `\"`, `\/`, `\\` or encoded as `\uXXXX` characters, leaving the `dataString` looking like this:

```
{"field":"User-String with \"encoded\" characters!\r\nSome other characters look like \u00FC or \u00E4.\r\nQuestion Marks?, Exclamation Marks!, 'SingleQuotes' and who knows what!"}
```

So `... echo {"field":"..."} | ...` would be the String to execute.

I've tried so far to use double quotes and single quotes or to escape with `^` but its not working properly. At least if i try to simulate it with `echo String | cat > testfile.txt` in my terminal window.

**What characters i need to escape and how?**

Edit:
Since i chose the solution of devplayer for the call with file transfer, you might think i am done. But now i got another Kind of call without a file transfer an without a need of a pipe, but with the same issue of user input that needs to be escaped properly.

It's like:

```
curl ... -d "<properly escaped string>" --url ...
```

Comment: This might sound a little bit silly, but do even have curl installed on your Windows OS?

Comment: Yes, i'm already doing successful requests with this kind of command

Comment: Mmm try typing spaces around the `&` and for `”` just use double quotes like this `””`

Answer (score 0):

how about if you pass your long string content as a file to your command?
I.e. store your **datastring** in a **file.txt**
and feed the contents of the file to the command as follows:

```
/path/to/curl --cacert '/path/to/cert/cacert.pem' -X POST"&options&" -A """&useragent&""""&referer&" -F "&fileParamName&"=@-;type="&fileMIME&";filename=^"""&filename&"^"" --url """&url&""" < file.txt
```

?

Comment: Then i would only need to give the filepath instead of the dash `-`. No need for `< file.txt`. But there are quite a lot of "Files" and wich would fill up the hard drive very fast. I am limited in terms of space, thats why i am trying without an actual file.

Comment: you can always reuse the same file, no need to stack them. it's true that it's not a solution to the actual question , but is it a solution to the problem?

Comment: This is the solution i chose, but only because it solved a size issue as well. Since this is not the answer to the question, i will not mark it as the accepted answer. Unless the community thinks it is. ;)